# how can i resolve unmet dependencies in 16.04

Tags: dependencies

I cannot install packages in my 16.04 ubuntu server. Getting below error while doing the same:

```
root@ubuntu:~# apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 network-manager-gnome : Depends: libappindicator3-1 (>= 0.4.90) but it is not installed
                         Depends: libnma0 (= 1.2.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.4) but it is not installed
                         Depends: libsecret-1-0 (>= 0.7) but it is not installed
                         Depends: policykit-1-gnome
                         Depends: dbus-x11
                         Recommends: gnome-keyring
                         Recommends: mobile-broadband-provider-info but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
root@ubuntu:~#
```

Same error is being displayed after trying to "apt-get" every package.

Help needed

Comment: Some of the packages I looked up are available (https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/libnma0 https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libappindicator3-1) so I'd check your sources, and `sudo apt-get update` and read the output looking for something wrong (ie. lines output are without error, expected lines are there) as packages should appear. The output will also show what mirror you're using which you can check up on https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors to see it's up-to-date

Comment: You could try using `aptitude` instead and do `sudo aptitude dist-upgrade`. Please see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1155022/968501) for help.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion in the error message to run `sudo apt-get -f install`?

Comment: `apt-cache policy` please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Please [edit] your post to include the output of `apt-get -f install`