# Errors while installing any package in Ubuntu 16.04: 'Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)'

Tags: apt, dpkg, python3

There are lot of similar question (and corresponding solution) on this error here. However, I do  need a fresh solution to my problem. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit machine with python 2.7.

I get the following error while trying to install any `pacakge`. The same error prints after `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

```
   Errors were encountered while processing:
  /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-cryptography_1.2.3-1ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb
  /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-urllib3_1.13.1-2ubuntu0.16.04.3_all.deb
  /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-louis_2.6.4-2ubuntu0.4_all.deb
  E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Following the solution available here, I tried the following:

1. Tried to remove python3 (which I do not remember how it got installed in the first place!)

```
   sudo apt-get remove python3
```

I get the following error:

```
    Errors were encountered while processing:
    python3-oauthlib
    gnome-orca
    python3-plainbox
    python3-lxml
    python3-requests
    python3-urllib3
    python3-cyrptography
    python3-louis
    python3-checkbox-support
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

2. Next I tried to do this

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`. This worked with no errors.

Following this command, I tried this

`sudo apt-get -f install`. After this I get the following error:

```
     Errors were encountered while processing:
     /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-cryptography_1.2.3-1ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb
     /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-urllib3_1.13.1-2ubuntu0.16.04.3_all.deb
     /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-louis_2.6.4-2ubuntu0.4_all.deb
     E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This is the same error as the first one.

I also tried to install a `package` after removing the `.deb` files from `/var/cache/apt/archives/`. Still it prints the same error.

Any solution to this would be very helpful. For now, I am not interested in updating my Ubuntu 16.04 to latest version available.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1155019/968501 and https://askubuntu.com/q/1164480/968501