# Sudo apt upgrade doesn't work !! unmet dependencies Python 3

Tags: upgrade, dependencies, python3

I recently installed Python3.8 and everything worked fine as far as using various versions of Python successfully in the terminal.  After several days I called `sudo apt update`, which worked just fine, but when I did `sudo apt upgrade` I received the error message below.  I tried to do `sudo apt --fix-broken install` and a sub-process returned an error code.

When i tried `sudo apt upgrade`

**Output**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
dh-python : Depends: python3-distutils but it is not installed
python3-dev : Depends: python3-distutils (>= 3.6.7-1~) but it is not installed
python3-pip : Depends: python3-distutils but it is not installed
python3-setuptools : Depends: python3-distutils but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When i tried `sudo apt --fix-broken install`

**Output**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libllvm7 libllvm8 libllvm8:i386 libpython3.7-minimal libpython3.7-stdlib
  python3.7-minimal
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  python3-distutils python3-lib2to3
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python3-distutils python3-lib2to3
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 122 not upgraded.
10 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/222 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,143 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 201984 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3-lib2to3_3.6.9-1~18.04_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-lib2to3 (3.6.9-1~18.04) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-lib2to3_3.6.9-1~18.04_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib2to3/Grammar.txt', which is also in package python3.8-lib2to3 3.8.0-1+bionic2
Preparing to unpack .../python3-distutils_3.6.9-1~18.04_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-distutils (3.6.9-1~18.04) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-distutils_3.6.9-1~18.04_all.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/README', which is also in package python3.8-distutils 3.8.0-1+bionic2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-lib2to3_3.6.9-1~18.04_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-distutils_3.6.9-1~18.04_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I also tried to do this `sudo apt --fix-broken install python3-distutils`

**Output**

````
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-distutils : Depends: python3-lib2to3 (>= 3.6.4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).```
````

I also tried `sudo apt --fix-broken install python3-lib2to3`

**Output**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dh-python : Depends: python3-distutils but it is not going to be installed
 python3-dev : Depends: python3-distutils (>= 3.6.7-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 python3-pip : Depends: python3-distutils but it is not going to be installed
 python3-setuptools : Depends: python3-distutils but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Thanks for any help that can be provided!

**Update**

when I tried to do `sudo apt install aptitude`

**Output**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 aptitude : Depends: aptitude-common (= 0.8.10-6ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libcwidget3v5 but it is not going to be installed
 dh-python : Depends: python3-distutils but it is not going to be installed
 python3-dev : Depends: python3-distutils (>= 3.6.7-1~) but it is not going to be installed
 python3-pip : Depends: python3-distutils but it is not going to be installed
 python3-setuptools : Depends: python3-distutils but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Try this first 
`sudo apt update -y
sudo apt clean
sudo apt autoremove` and then `sudo apt --fix-broken install`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removed python3 hoping to reinstall it, but cannot do it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1155019/removed-python3-hoping-to-reinstall-it-but-cannot-do-it)

Comment: Also you might want to try option #2 in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1164505/968501)

Comment: Looks like you tried to use packages from two different (and incompatible) sources: Example: `Unpacking python3-lib2to3 (3.6.9-1~18.04) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-lib2to3_3.6.9-1~18.04_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib2to3/Grammar.txt', which is also in package python3.8-lib2to3 3.8.0-1+bionic2`. Pick one source, delete the other source, and uninstall ALL packages from the deleted source.

Comment: Please indicate what version of Ubuntu you are running and add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: In my case a `sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite "/var/cache/apt/archives/python3-lib2to3...deb"` did the trick, as suggested [https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2397244&p=13787159#post13787159](here). Obviously, first do a `ls /var/cache/apt/archives/` to see which filename it has and place it in the command. This has worked with all failed packages which said `which is also in package`.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the following instead:

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Since dist-upgrade also handles new package dependencies.

This was explained here: 
[Why use apt-get upgrade instead of apt-get dist-upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194651/why-use-apt-get-upgrade-instead-of-apt-get-dist-upgrade)

Comment: Why would you upgrade the distro? He wanted to upgrade only packages not the Ubuntu distribution.

Comment: dist-upgrade has nothing to do with upgrading the distro/release. Try reading the link I just posted. If you want to upgrade the Ubuntu release you run the command: sudo do-release-upgrade, which is something entirely different than an apt command.

Comment: dist-upgrade will aslo remove packages but upgrade wont

Comment: After doing the suggestions mentioned I still am getting the same errors.  Particularly, I get these errors after doing sudo apt --fix-broken install:

```Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-lib2to3_3.6.9-1~18.04_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-distutils_3.6.9-1~18.04_all.deb```

Comment: Did you run sudo apt clean ?? Because this should remove all packages in var/cache/apt/archives

Answer (score 2):

Easiest method:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude-common libcwidget3v5
sudo aptitude upgrade
```

**OR**

```
sudo apt-get install python3-distutils
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this issue , if you want to upgrade but can't:

**Way 1**

Step 1 : open [Software & Updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4NRj.png).

Step 2 : change `Download from` to [Main Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jweWP.png)

Step 3 : open Terminal (`ctlr + alt + t`) then `sudo apt-get update` , then `sudo apt-get upgrade`

**Way 2 Remove PPA**

Step 1 : open [Software & Updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4NRj.png).

Step 2 : go to Other Software tab and choose the desire PPA from the list. Afterwards click on [Remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BjQ2.jpg) to remove it.

*OR*

You can remove it using terminal : `sudo apt-add-repository -r PPA_Name/ppa`

**Way 3 :**

[Read This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades)

also try to use this commands , may it help: `sudo apt clean` , `sudo apt autoclean` , `sudo apt autoremove`.

Hope that helps you!